# Basic idea of Lisp Macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I try to do a very simple thing in Lisp - to find a way to turn on a global valuable nodebug t and then some of debug format form would be silence.  To do that, I found I cannot grasp the difference of the following:

```
(defparameter *nodebug* t)
(setf x 1)

;;; the basic function 

(format t "x is ~a" x) ;;; generate -> x is 1


;;; try to use function not macro

(defun formatdf (stream string &rest allparm) ;;; later add (if ...
(format stream string allparm))

(formatdf t "x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is (1)


;;; try to use macro

(defmacro formatdm (stream string &rest allparm) ;;; later add (if ...
(format stream string allparm))

(formatdm t "x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is (X)
```

It seems the generated code (or the function one) is not the same as the original format form.  What should be my next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your "function one" is that you pass `&rest` parameter to the `format` function as is. Passing `x` to `formatdf` results in the creating a list containing one parameter, that is bound to `allparm`.
So if you want to just print the first parameter you should write:

```
 (formatdf t "x is ~a" (car x))
```

or fix `format` inside `formatdf` in the next way:

```
(apply #'format stream string allparm)
```

Comment: You can optimize that so you don't have to cons a list: `(apply #'format stream string allparm)`.  `apply` expects that the last argument is actually a list of arguments, but since we're providing a `&rest` argument, the implementation is free to optimize e.g. in such way that the parameters are left in the stack without consing a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defmacro formatdm (stream string &rest allparm) ;;; later add (if ...
  (format stream string allparm))
```

A macro should return source code, not execute. Here it is only useful to see what the value of `allparm` is at macro expansion time. It is a part of the source code: `(x)`.

You need to return a list with the necessary instructions - here the code to call format.

This is a very good book about Lisp, which also should explain the basics of macros: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 0):

(defparameter *nodebug* t)
(setf x 1)
(format t "x is ~a" x) ;;; generate -> x is 1

;;; to generate the same and prepare for nodebug version, the following is needed:

;;; using defmacro

(defmacro formatdmadv (stream string &rest allparm) 
  `(format ,stream ,string ,@allparm))

(formatdmadv t "formatdmadv x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is 1 <-- macro correct

;;; or using defun as suggested

(formatdf_car t "formatdf_car x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is 1 <-- fun correct

(defun formatdf (stream string &rest allparm) 
  (apply #'format (list* stream string allparm)))

(formatdf t "formatdf using apply x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is 1 <-- fun correct

;;; ---- the below is incorrect

(defun formatdf_err (stream string &rest allparm) (format stream string allparm))

(formatdf_err t "formatdf_err: x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is (1)

(defun formatdf_car (stream string &rest allparm) 
  (format stream string (car allparm)))

(defmacro formatdm (stream string &rest allparm) 
  (format stream string allparm))

(formatdm t "formatdm x is ~a" x)  ;;; generate -> x is (X)

;;; ----- test confirming the findings

(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(formatdm t "formatdm x is ~a" x)))

(pprint (macroexpand '(formatdm t "formatdm x is ~a" x)))

(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(formatdm t "formatdm b" c)))

;;; --- incorrect one and do not even generate the source code even

(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(formatdmadv t "formatdmadv x is ~a" x)))

(pprint (macroexpand '(formatdmadv t "formatdmadv x is ~a" x)))

(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(formatdmadv t "formatdmadv b" c)))